# Check custom protocol exist or not

Tags: javascript, custom-protocol

I have to identify whether custom protocol is installed or not, For that i tried `protocolCheck.js` and also i tried

```
try {
      window.location = "custom:";
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.toString().search("NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL") != -1) {
        alert("No protocol registered");
   }
```

With this i can able to detect and launch custom protocol but My problem is, I have to only detect whether custom protocol is register or not. I don't want to launch or don't want to appear browser dialog.

Can anyone help me to get this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without launching the application.

Comment: That's what i think, but posted this question for better approach

Comment: Also, didn't you meant `window.location.href = "protocol:"` instead of `window.location.protocol("custom:")`. `window.location.protocol` is not a function.

Comment: Yes, Bymistake i added `location.protocol`